# Can one page be simultaneously in two working sets?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

I'm new to the concept of paging and virtual memory.
I think the answer is NO because if a page can be simultaneously in two working sets, it would lead to a process interference with another process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrect.

In every logical memory system I am aware of there is a range of shared addresses for the system. They are protected from "interference" by limiting access by processor privilege levels.

In addition, processes can create shared pages in any mode (called global sections, shared memory). These can be mapped to multiple processes. If applications use shared pages, they have to synchronize their access to them or suffer the consequences for not doing so.